# consistent writes to a file while preserving its inode

Tags: bash, write

What is the best way to edit a file consistently (consistency used here in the database systems sense of the term) without changing its inode?  Normally, I would write to a temporary file and then call `rename(2)`, but since that changes the inode, it's not an option.  I have in mind something like `modify_file <file >tmp && cat <tmp >file`, but for which the modification either occurs completely or not at all (`modify_file` is a process that modifies the content of stdin).  Is this possible using ordinary shell utilities?  I think the following might cover most cases (apart from `SIGKILL` and losing power):

```
(
    flock -x 9
    trap '' INT TERM # (perhaps other signals)
    modify_file <file >tmp && cat <tmp >file
) 9>>file
```

For the sub-case that one wants to change only a certain byte sequence of the file, would `ed` be a better choice?

Comment: Your shell script won't account for running out of space in the filesystem or getting a write error because of media errors. If you really need to use the same inode, you should write new data to a separate area of the file, call `fsync`, read the data back to make sure it's OK, then change whatever data structures are necessary to refer to the new data.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Thanks, that's an interesting approach.  Running out of space is not a concern for this application, but random media errors potentially are (less-than-reliable network file system).

Comment: `ed` reads and rewrites the whole file (very inefficiently) -- it does not edit it in place and does not offer any atomicity guarantees. And I don't think that it guarantees that it will preserve the inode, either.

Comment: @mosvy: Thanks for clarifying.  I have little experience with `ed` but for some reason thought it could perform in-place edits.

Comment: Why is keeping the same inode number important? What are the other processes that need to see a consistent version of the file? Just this same script or something else too?

Comment: @ilkkachu: There are two scripts that access the file, a writer and a reader, and then other processes (of which there could be several thousand concurrently) call one of these scripts to access the file (actually there are many such files which together constitute a simple database). The inode is maintained because each file is used as its own lock.  I'm considering changing this (using an empty file as the lock, which would allow for inode changes), but that would double the number of inodes required and the target filesystem is inode-poor.

Comment: GNU ed consistently retains the inode.  As does freebsd's ed.  I don't think I've ever run across an ed that doesn't.   Anything that opens an existing file for write or append will do the same, including shell redirection, tee, vi, nano, ..... - this probably depends on the filesystem the file is on more than anything else. i.e. it's not anything special that programs do, it's just how the fs works when writing to an existing file.

Comment: Do your reader processes use an exclusive lock, too? If so, you can use [mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at/731634#731634) as your locking mechanism, which only uses an inode (or two) while the lock is active.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Currently I use a shared lock for the reader and an exclusive lock for the writer, but I could use exclusive locks for both.  Would using a directory as the lock be different than using a separate file as the lock in terms of the number of required inodes?

Comment: I guess when using a directory as the lock (`if mkdir $file.lock`) you'd only need one additional inode for the duration of the lock. If you use a file hard link as a lock (`locktmp="lock.$$.$RANDOM"; touch $locktmp; if ln $locktmp $file.lock`) you'd need one additional inode for the duration of the lock plus one inode each time a process tries to get a lock.